# Regex matches method showing false everytime

Tags: java, regex

This is my code in which I am trying to enter an IP Adress and check if it matches with the guidelines -
 Number of digits less than 3, and numbers between 0-255.
Eg - 111.245.0.11
But every time I run the program, the matches method is outputting false, whatever be the input.

MAIN CLASS

```
package Rough;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Regex
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String ip = sc.next();
            System.out.println(ip.matches(new MyRegex().pattern));
        }
    }
}
```

MYRegex Class

```
package Rough;
public class MyRegex extends Regex
{
    String limit = "(\\d{1,2} | (0,1)\\d{2} | 2[0-4]\\d | 25[0-5])";
    public String pattern = limit+"\\."+ limit + "\\."+ limit + "\\." + limit;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tested that "limit" matches a single number yet? (I'm concerned that the spaces may well be relevant.) It's not clear why these are instance fields, either...

Comment: In the ``limit`` variable, you use ``(0,1)\\d{2}``. The comma is treated as a literal and since a comma is not present in an ip adress, the matching fails. You probably want ``(0|1)\\d{2}`` or ``[01]\\d{2}`` instead.

Comment: Check this example: https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/